# TS not working after update

Tags: typescript, webpack

I updated TS to new version

And after running website I have this error

> > Failed to compile.
>
> /Users/mrfix/Documents/GitHub/falco-web/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts
>   [tsl] ERROR in
>   /Users/mrfix/Documents/GitHub/*******/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts(1344,19)
>         TS1005: ';' expected.

Here is my tsconfig

```
 {
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/webpacker": "^3.3.0",
    "@types/accounting": "^0.4.1",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.8",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^2.1.0",
    "honeybadger-js": "^0.5.2",
    "npm": "^5.8.0",
    "ts-loader": "3.5.0",
    "typescript": "^2.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@honeybadger-io/webpack": "^1.0.4",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.1"
  }
}
```

Any suggestions how to handle it?

Comment: Did you update the global typescript compiler as well ? (`npm update -g typescript`) That line contains ts 2.8 sytax, so some part of your build is still using an older ts version

Comment: Yes and this not fixed it@TitianCernicova-Dragomir